# Learning python: Why these two function yield different results?

Tags: python, function

```
def fun1(a):
  a=[7, 8]

def fun2(a):
  a[0]=7
  a[1]=8


q=[1,2]

fun1(q)
print(q)

fun2(q)
print(q)
```

The first one prints out: [1, 2] which means that q has not been changed using fun1.
The second one prints out: [1, 2] which means that q is changed when I use fun2.

Why is this happening? What is the underlying difference between the two functions?

Comment: The first one simply assigns a new list to the local variable `a`, the other *mutates* whatever object `a` is referring to.

Comment: In `fun1`, you create a new object `a` rather than in `fun2`, you modify the values in `a`

Comment: `a = ...` is a simple assignment, and makes the local variable named `a` refer to a different object. `a[0] = ...` is shorthand for `a.__setitem__(0, ...)`, which mutates the list already bound to `a`.

Comment: I would recommend reading this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Also, good idea to read the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Comment: @BehzadDanaei also, see the linked duplicate